# Spring batch- read from SQL server and write to Cassandra

Tags: sql-server, spring, cassandra, spring-batch

I have a scenario with spring batch where I need read data from ms SQL server database and write it to the Cassandra database.
Am new to batch processing not much resources getting in Google to understand more on this,
Could you please share inputs in the same

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You question is very light on detail and a little too open-ended so I wanted to warn you that there's a chance the community will vote to close it for those reasons.

Based on what you've provided, it sounds like you've got a streaming use case where you have an app "service" that would be the source of the data and publish it on a messaging/event platform and other systems/services can subscribe to those events.

You can use Kafka or Pulsar as the platform and Cassandra is one of the sinks. If you're interested in trying it out, [Astra Streaming](https://www.datastax.com/products/astra-streaming) is a streaming-as-a-service backed by Pulsar with [Astra DB](http://dtsx.io/3mw14tX) (Cassandra-as-a-service) as the sink.

Astra Streaming and DB have free tiers which don't require a credit card so you can quickly do POCs without having to worry about downloading/installing/configuring clusters.

As a side note, Astra DB comes with ready-to-use [Stargate.io](https://stargate.io/) -- a data platform that allows you to connect to Cassandra using REST, GraphQL and JSON/Doc APIs so you can easily build applications on top of Cassandra using APIs. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Erick Ramirez, now I have made my question more simple , could you please comment on same.

Comment: Wow! You've completely changed the question. 